# Transform list into certain format

Tags: python-3.x, list, string-formatting

I have a relatively obscure requirement and have not been to succeed in getting the result. Hence I am trying to figure out if it's even possible to obtain the result.

I have a list:

```
x = ['a','b','c',  ...]
```

I need to transform it into the following:

```
y = "VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ..."
```

Main reason being, I have read some literature that using `ANY (VALUES (),(),...` increases the speed of PostgreSQL query by 200x and am trying to format my list into that specific format which I shall be placing into my query.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with something like this:

```
x = ['a','b','c']
y = "VALUES (" + "), (".join(x) +")"
```